# sitecore: Clear single image from media cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, sitecore, sitecore7

We have made a custom image cropper.

The idea is that it saves a query string in a field in the item.
Then on rendering we add that query string to the image url.

We added a getMediaStream pipeline. Inside this pipeline we crop the image using ImageProcessor based on the querystring that the image has.

This all works... once.

After it worked once the image is in the media cache and we never get back inside the getMediaStream pipeline. Because when you recrop, you don't change the image but you change that querystring.

We are searching for a way that when we save a new crop, we clear the media cache from that image.
We have tried the following:

```
var mediaItem = new MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
var mediaOptions = new MediaOptions();
var mediaStream = MediaManager.Cache.GetStream(media, mediaOptions);

MediaStream cachedStream = null;
MediaManager.Cache.AddStream(media, mediaOptions, mediaStream, out cachedStream);
```

We get the media cache stream and try setting it to zero, but that gives us the following exception:  `Could not create the buffer file needed for stream sharing`

Any ideas if it's possible to clear a single item from the media cache?

Comment: Passing different parameters will usually cause the media to be generated and cached. If you always pass the same parameters it is not expected to hit the pipelines again for performance reasons. Are you saying it is not working like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to remove a single item from the cache. Sitecore stores one image in the cache per unique request. If you have genuinely updated the querystring that is used to request the image then Sitecore should call the `getmediastream` pipeline again.

My guess is that your custom querystring is not actually being passed as part of the request.

Sitecore stores a ini file alongside the cached images, It has a section per image request and stores the querystring that was requested. Bottom line, if your querystring is unique then you should hit the pipeline.